# Calling a value from has_one association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I am trying to grab some info from a has_one association but I can't get the correct way to call it. I have 2 tables a students table which has_one emergency_contact. The emergency_contact table has a foreign key value student_id. I am trying to link_to the record that the foreign key is attached to in the emergency_contact table and I just can't seem to get it correct.

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
self.primary_key = :student_id
has_one :emergency_contact
```

emergency_contact.rb

```
class EmergencyContact < ApplicationRecord
self.primary_key = :contact_id
belongs_to  :student, optional: true
```

students/show.html.erb

```
<%= emergency_contact_path(@student.student_id) %>
```

Right now I am just getting directed to the value of student_id, which for example student_id = 5. When really the contact_id of the emergency_contact.contact_id = 1. How can I get that 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `foreign_key` for `has_one`:

```
has_one :emergency_contact, foreign_key: 'contact_id'
```

Link is:

```
<%= emergency_contact_path(@student.emergency_contact.contact_id) %>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your help!